# Unable to move next screen in React navigation V5 Using Firebase Auth

Tags: android, react-native, firebase-authentication, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

Im using React navigation version 5 with Firebase integration. Using that I'm trying to make authentication flow. I almost done a Signing flow and it works Perfect, but after Firebase Signed in it will not render and it is in still same SignIn Page in mobile. PFB the Code of My AppRouter Page.

```
import React, { Component, useEffect } from 'react'
import { View, Platform, TouchableOpacity, Text, Image, Dimensions, Slider, Button, ActivityIndicator, Alert } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import RootStackScreen from '../Router/RootStackScreen'
import HomeStackScreen from './TabScreens'
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';
import { Authcontext } from '../Components/context'
import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth';
import Home from '../Pages/OnboardingScreen/Home';
var { height, width } = Dimensions.get('window')
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
const AppRouter = ({navigation}) => {
    const initialoginState = {
        isLoading: true,
        email: null,
        userToken: null
    };
    const loginReducer = (prevState, action) => {
        switch (action.type) {
            case 'RETRIVE_TOKEN':
                return {
                    ...prevState,
                    userToken: action.token,
                    isLoading: false,
                };
            case 'LOGIN':
                return {
                    ...prevState,
                    email: action.id,
                    userToken: action.token,
                    isLoading: false,
                };
            case 'LOGOUT':
                return {
                    ...prevState,
                    email: null,
                    userToken: null,
                    isLoading: false,
                };
            case 'REGISTER':
                return {
                    ...prevState,
                    email: action.id,
                    userToken: action.token,
                    isLoading: false,
                };
        }
    }
    const [loginState, dispatch] = React.useReducer(loginReducer, initialoginState)
    const authContext = React.useMemo(() => ({
        signIn: async (email, password) => {
            let userToken;
            userToken = null;
            if (email !== '' && password !== '') {
                auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                    .then(async (success) => {
                        try {
                            await AsyncStorage.setItem('userToken', success.user.uid)
                        } catch (e) {
                            console.log(e)
                            Alert.alert('Shopping', e)
                        }
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        if (error.code === 'auth/email-already-in-use') {
                            Alert.alert('Shopping', 'That email address is already in use!')
                        }
                        if (error.code === 'auth/invalid-email') {
                            Alert.alert('Shopping', 'That email address is invalid!')
                        }
                        Alert.alert('Shopping', error.code)
                    });
            } else {
                Alert.alert('Shopping', 'Invalid Email / Password')
            }
            dispatch({ type: 'LOGIN', id: email, token: userToken , isLoading: false})
        },
        signUp: () => {
         //Pending
        },
        signOut: async () => {
            try {
                await AsyncStorage.removeItem('userToken')
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e)
            }
            dispatch({ type: 'LOGOUT' })
        },
    }), [])
    useEffect(() => {
        setTimeout(async () => {
            let userToken;
            userToken = null;
            try {
                userToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userToken')
                console.log('token', userToken)
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e)
            }
            dispatch({ type: 'RETRIVE_TOKEN', token: userToken })
        }, 1000)
    }, []);
    if (loginState.isLoading) {
        return (
            <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
                <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="black" />
            </View>
        )
    }
    return (
        <Authcontext.Provider value={authContext}>
            <NavigationContainer>
                {loginState.userToken !== null ?
                    (
                        <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
                            <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={HomeStackScreen} />  //Dashboard Screens
                        </Drawer.Navigator>
                    ) :
                    <RootStackScreen />  //Authentication Screens
                }
            </NavigationContainer>
        </Authcontext.Provider>
    )
}
export default AppRouter
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to dispatch login inner signInWithEmailAndPassword then or userToken always will be null because of the async.

```
const authContext = React.useMemo(() => ({
        signIn: async (email, password) => {
            let userToken;
            userToken = null;
            if (email !== '' && password !== '') {
                auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                    .then(async (success) => {
                     dispatch({ type: 'LOGIN', id: email, token: userToken , isLoading: false})
                        try {
                            await AsyncStorage.setItem('userToken', success.user.uid)
                        } catch (e) {
                            console.log(e)
                            Alert.alert('Shopping', e)
                        }
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        if (error.code === 'auth/email-already-in-use') {
                            Alert.alert('Shopping', 'That email address is already in use!')
                        }
                        if (error.code === 'auth/invalid-email') {
                            Alert.alert('Shopping', 'That email address is invalid!')
                        }
                        Alert.alert('Shopping', error.code)
                    });
            } else {
                Alert.alert('Shopping', 'Invalid Email / Password')
            }
            
        },
        signUp: () => {
         //Pending
        },
        signOut: async () => {
            try {
                await AsyncStorage.removeItem('userToken')
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e)
            }
            dispatch({ type: 'LOGOUT' })
        },
    }), [])
```